# LDAP username redirect in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hopefully not much code but more guidance in this question.

I am authenticating users over LDAP to access 2 gateways.  The problem is that no matter what `Response.Redirect()` is set to it always redirects to a default.aspx page.  I'm sure this is something I need to adjust in Web.config, but I cannot find the right solution since it will be dynamic based on username.

```
IIS 7.5 
Windows Server 2008 R2
ASP.NET Framework 2.0 written in 3.5
Forms Authentication
```

Even with this I still get redirect to default.aspx

```
  <defaultDocument enabled="false">
            <files>
                <remove value="default.aspx" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
```

If you need anymore information please ask, thanks.

Comment: What does the authentication section of your web.config look like?

Comment: It is using Windows authentication.